# How to get the count separately after group by

Tags: pandas

`df_n_gender_grp = df_n_gender_prod_cat.groupby(['Gender','prod_cat'])`

My Out is below

```
    Gender  prod_cat
0   M   Books
1   M   Books
2   M   Electronics
3   M   Electronics
4   M   Books
100 F   Electronics
101 F   Electronics
102 F   Electronics
103 F   Electronics
104 F   Electronics
105 F   Clothing
106 F   Clothing
107 F   Clothing
108 F   Clothing
```

My Expected out is

First dataframe  in descending order of values

```
M Books       2
M Electronics 3
```

Second dataframe  in descending order of values

```
F Electronics 5
F Clothing    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for `Series` with `MultiIndex` [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
s = df_n_gender_prod_cat.groupby(['Gender','prod_cat']).size().sort_index(ascending=False)
print (s)
Gender  prod_cat   
M       Electronics    2
        Books          3
F       Electronics    5
        Clothing       4
dtype: int64
```

And then filter by `loc`

```
df1 = s.loc[['F']]
df2 = s.loc[['M']]
```

For DataFrame is necessary add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = s.loc[['F']].reset_index(name='count')
df2 = s.loc[['M']].reset_index(name='count')
```

Or add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) first:

```
df =  (df_n_gender_prod_cat.groupby(['Gender','prod_cat'])
                           .size()
                           .sort_index(ascending=False)
                           .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
  Gender     prod_cat  count
0      M  Electronics      2
1      M        Books      3
2      F  Electronics      5
3      F     Clothing      4
```

And then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Gender'].eq('F')]
df2 = df[df['Gender'].eq('M')]
```

Comment: `s = df_n_gender_prod_cat.groupby(['Gender','prod_cat']).size().sort_index(ascending=False)` its sorting on prod_cat not on count for me, any suggestion

Comment: got solution `s1 = df_n_gender_prod_cat.groupby(['Gender','prod_cat']).size().sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(name='count').sort_values(['count'],ascending=False)`